# How to extract information of review period from a journal using R

Tags: r, web

I want do a survey of the review period of the journal *scientific reports*, http://www.nature.com/srep/articles. I want to extract the submitting time and accepting time of each article within a time window (or the most recent 100 articles). Is there any suggestion of how to do that in R? The solution can be simple but I never used R for web scraping before. Some hints can be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can try

Compile your links in a csv file as the only change i see in the links is the `srepID` at the end, do it as shown below :

```
> head(links)
                                     links
1 http://www.nature.com/articles/srep20000
2 http://www.nature.com/articles/srep20001
3 http://www.nature.com/articles/srep20002
4 http://www.nature.com/articles/srep20003
5 http://www.nature.com/articles/srep20004
6 http://www.nature.com/articles/srep20005
```

then run the following code :

```
    library(rvest)
links <- read.csv("link.csv",T,"~")



for (i in 1:nrow(links)) {

url <- read_html(as.character(links[i,1]))

#Upload

links[i,2] <- url %>% 
        html_node("dd:nth-child(2) time") %>%
        html_text() %>%
        as.character()

#Accepted

links[i,3] <- url %>% 
  html_node("dd:nth-child(4) time") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()



}

colnames(links)[2] <- "Received"
colnames(links)[3] <- "Accepted"
```

You'll get the results as :

```
    > head(links)
                                     links         Received         Accepted
1 http://www.nature.com/articles/srep20000  15 October 2015 22 December 2015
2 http://www.nature.com/articles/srep20001  21 October 2015 22 December 2015
3 http://www.nature.com/articles/srep20002  20 October 2015 22 December 2015
4 http://www.nature.com/articles/srep20003 10 November 2015 22 December 2015
5 http://www.nature.com/articles/srep20004 15 November 2015 22 December 2015
6 http://www.nature.com/articles/srep20005 09 November 2015 22 December 2015
```

NOTE : Maximum the URLs , longer the time will be taken by the code for completion . Also the site doesn't allow botic action on its pages , so it won't be able to give you all info without using any alternate way .